# DOM HTML changing back

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form that creates a POST request that's handled first by Javascript, and then by PHP. My problem is that I want to change an image (the button) on submit, but when I do this, the image changes back to what it was previously. If I refresh the page, the image will go back to what I wanted to because of the PHP check. So, my guess is that the PHP is messing with the Javascript changing the image. Here's a simplified version of my code...

```
<?php
$image = "<input type=\"submit\" style=\"background-image: url(grey.png);\" onclick=\"like()\" value=\"\" />";
while($stmt->fetchColumn()) {
$image = "<input type=\"submit\" style=\"background-image: url(red.png);\" onclick=\"like()\" value=\"\" />";
}
echo "<form id='like' method='POST' action='action.php'><div id='images'>".$image."</div></form>";
?>
<script>
function like() {
    var html = document.getElementById("images").innerHTML;
    document.forms['like'].submit();
    if(document.getElementById("images").innerHTML.indexOf("grey") != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = "<input type=\"submit\" style=\"background-image: url(red.png);\" onclick=\"like()\" value=\"\" />";
    }
   return false;
}
  </script>
```

I don't believe I missed anything important or left anything unchanged for the example, but if you notice any mistakes, please let me know.

Thank you!

Edit: ignore the while loop. I know that I didn't include the other parts to the sql statement.

Comment: I'm confused. The image changes on submit (OK), but then you actually post the form? That means visiting another page, JavaScript doesn't persist onto the next page.

Comment: It doesn't change pages. It runs the PHP on the current page. I hope that's what you mean.

Comment: it sounds like the php conditions are not correctly catching on submit, but it's odd that it catches it on refresh.  Seeing the actual bit in your `if(...)` would be good.

Comment: How does it "[run] the PHP on the current page"?

Comment: @IanClark It doesn't. I think the OP means that the form points to the same page. Which, yes, does mean that the page is reloaded, which is what you meant, of course. But since the example has the php outputting the button style based on some condition, the js doesn't need to persist, since the php does the work on load.

Comment: @Anthony yes, I think so, I wanted to let him arrive at that conclusion!

Comment: @IanClark - Hmm, the example does have the `onclick` function returning false but also has the function calling submit before the color change. Bet that's no good either.

Comment: @Anthony yes I was puzzled by that too! But I suppose if you take a look, it's on `click` of the input, rather than some recursive loop called when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Anthony I changed the code to my more updated version where I use a while loop. I have tried this and an if statement to see if the table contains a certain row, but I didn't include the rest of the pdo.

Comment: And yes, it points to the php on the same page.

Comment: Also, the `submit` button doesn't have a `name`, so I'm curious what the condition is that checks it, since it wouldn't be `$_GET['submit_button_name'`.  Very curious.

Comment: For the PHP, it checks for a post value to run.

Comment: @user2693030 - Not based on your update. This sounds very complicated. Have you tried simplifying your actual code so that instead of it being based on database stuff or post variables, you just have the PHP check if the submit button is in the post, meaning it was submitted?

Comment: @Anthony I haven't tried that, but would it make a difference? The PHP is working correctly. It's creating a row in my sql table, and checking to see if the row exists correctly.

Comment: Well, it's not working, as you're here, and if it works with much simpler logic, it means he problem is in your condition, not with anything else.

Comment: @Anthony I think I know what you mean now, but I need the database values, sql, etc. because it's a like system and I need to keep record of who has liked what. I'm trying to make it so upon clicking, it changes, and upon refreshing, it stays changed.

Comment: dude, it doesn't matter how the page will work. you're trying to fix a problem. You won't ever know if that issue is with one part or another if you can't test them independently. at this point, your presumption on where the problem is is unlikely, your actual goal is really unclear, and you're example code doesn't seem to represent the most simple version of your actual code. I tested your code, and the button stays red after submit. But i'm not sure if that's the goal or even the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the slight reworking of your code that I tested. It looks like it's working to me:

```
<?php

$submit_color = "grey.png";
if($_POST['submit']) {
    $submit_color = "red.png";
}

echo "<form id='like' method='POST' action=''>
<div id='images'>
<input name='submit' type='submit' style='background-image: url($submit_color);' onclick='like()' value='submit' />
</div>
</form>";
?>
<script>
function like() {
    var html = document.getElementById("images").innerHTML;
    document.forms['like'].submit();
    if(document.getElementById("images").innerHTML.indexOf("grey") != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = "<input name='submit' type='submit' style='background-image: url(red.png);' onclick='like()' value='submit' />";
    }
   return false;
}
  </script>
```